# Mosaico: Where can I find the source code of my mailing?

Tags: mosaico

we are using CiviCRM 5.4.0 and just got the Mosaico extension started to send our newsletter.
Now I have run into the following problem:
In the past I would take the source code of the mailing, create a .html file out of it and upload this to our homepage to back up a link people could click on - so for example it would say "January 2019 Newsletter", you could click on it and would be provided with an online version of the newsletter we had also send as an email.

Now, I am using Mosaico and don't know how to go about this situation anymore...I can not find the source code of the mailing to create the .html to then incorporate into our homepage...

**So my questions would be - how can I obtain either the source code or a clickable link I can include into our homepage?**

Thank you for any answers!

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can set the "Mailing Visibility" option (accessed by clicking the "Advanced Mailing Options" button on the 3. Options page of the Mosaico workflow) to "Public Pages" which will create a public HTML page that visitors can view, accessed by a tokenized link in the email itself. You should be able to get the HTML from this page and add it to your homepage... or just add a link to that public page.

> **Mailing Visibility**
>
> This option controls who can view the contents of
>   this email on your website. The link can be included by inserting the
>   "Mailing permalink" token (place it in a link when composing in HTML
>   mode).
>
> The options for mailing visibility are:
>
> "Public Pages" will make the content of this mailing viewable everyone
>   who has the permission "view public CiviMail content". Note that even
>   people who did not receive the mailing would be able to find it via
>   search engines. "User and User Admin Only" means that only users that
>   received the mailing or administrators can view this email on your
>   website; users must be logged in to view the message.

[image: Mailing Visibility]

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a copy of the mailing? As a workaround you can view the source code of the email in your email program (Outlook, webmail, etc) and use that.